# How to read all the thumb nails of videos in a folder and display them in a picture box grid

Tags: c#, video

I have a 3 by 3 grid of picture boxes on a form, and I intend to read all the thumbnails from the videos folder and display each thumb nail on its corresponding picture box in the grid. I used LINQ to get nine video files from the video folder like below.

```
var location = File.ReadAllLines("path.txt").ToList()[0];

// List all the files in the folder and take only nine
// paths because grid contains 9 picture boxes
var videoFiles = Directory.GetFiles(location).Where(x => x.Contains(".mp4") || x.Contains(".avi")).Take(9);
```

Then after searching through some posts here on Stack Overflow on how to get the thumbnail of an image with C#, I found a post referencing the use of **nreco.VideoConverter** which has a class called `FFMpegConverter` that has a method that takes the input path of the video file as the first parameter and a second parameter for writing the thumb nail image to a file.

I applied the code below to generate nine different thumbnails of the videos using the library.

```
// The list that holds the thumb nails is at the top of the class
private List<Image> thumbNails = new List<Image> ();

// Use a counter variable to save each thumb nail to a unique file name
var id = 1;
// Read the thumbnail of each video file and add to our list
foreach (var videoFile in videoFiles)
{
    // Use NRECO to get the thumb nails from each video
    var converter = new FFMpegConverter();
    converter.GetVideoThumbnail(videoFile, "sample" + id.ToString() + ".png");

    // Build a bitmap from the output stream
    var bitmap = Image.FromFile("sample" + id.ToString() + ".png");

    // Add the bitmap to the bitmap list
    if(bitmap != null)
    {
        thumbNails.Add(bitmap);
    }
    // Increment the counter
    id += 1;
}

// Loop through the picture box array and assign each picture box a thumb nail image
foreach(var image in  thumbNails)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j< 3; j++)
        {
            pictureBoxes[i, j].Image = image;
        }
    }
}
```

I expected to see each picture box on the grid with a different thumb nail image, but they are all showing the same thumb nail for one single video. How do I fix this and make each picture box display its own thumbnail from the list?

[image]

Comment: I can't test your code so it's just a guess but would using **new** help with getting unique bitmaps? Try as: `var bitmap = new Image.FromFile`...

Comment: Okay will sure try using a bitmap and update you if it works

Comment: @VC.One, The bug was in how I was declaring and using the output stream for the bitmap in the loop. I re initialized the path inside the loop and it would save the thumb nails as expected.

Comment: Superstar C# programmers use ***consistent*** code formatting, not formatting that is all over the place (and no, talking about tools is just a bad excuse). See for example the [Jon Skeet Decree](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/03/14/podcast-123-jon-skeet-wants-you-to-be-a-feminist/) - to whom you once compared yourself. If they don't, they can't call themselves superstar C# programmers.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, Hi. Am still a super star C# programmer because of the projects I have completed using .Net and Emgu CV. Jon Skeet has never used Emgu CV and doesn't do image processing, just because someone has better Stackoverflow reputation doesn't mean he is a better programmer.

Answer (score 2):

The bug in my code was I was not re-initializing the path to save each thumb nail inside the loop. The code below generates all the thumbnails and displays them in the picture grid.

```
// Create an instance for the converter outside the loop
var converter = new FFMpegConverter();

// Loop through the video files 
// and read the thumbnails
foreach (var videoFile in videoFiles)
{
    // Combine the path with our save location
    var path = Path.Combine(documentsFolder, id.ToString() + "sample.jpg");
    converter.GetVideoThumbnail(videoFile, path);

    // Dispose the object
    // Build a new bitmap from the saved thumb nail
    id += 1;
}

// Loop through the documents folder and  
// get all the files that contain sample
var images = Directory.GetFiles(documentsFolder).Where(x => x.Contains("sample")).ToArray();
var p = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        pictureBoxes[i, j].ImageLocation = images[p++];
    }
}
```